# hive group by and order by collect list

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

`select B.name, count(B.items) as count, concat_ws('|',collect_list(B.items)) as items from (select distinct name,items,item_rank from SourceA)B group by B.name order by B.item_rank`

**error invalid column reference item_rank**

try to output `nameofperson,count(items),list of items (pen,paper,book..)` at the output  but the order should be maintained from `item_rank` in ascending order

`example : pen item_rank 1, paper item_rank 2, book item_rank 3`

item order should be in ascending as per rank like pen, paper,book in collect_list

my output of collect_list is screwed up pen,book,paper, its not following rank when i keep order by inside subquery

if i keep order by outside i get **error invalid column reference item_rank**

where is it going wrong

thanks

Comment: I think you missed space between item_rank and from in your query

Comment: no its not space issue, i typed it wrong here,

Comment: i doubt you group by is missing .. concat_ws('|',collect_list(B.items))